# Getting number of subscription upgrades with API

Tags: php, api, subscription, recurly

In Recurly there is [option](https://docs.recurly.com/docs/subscriptions#changing-subscriptions) for upgrading or downgrading a subscription.

I wonder if it's possible to get a list of upgrades or downgrades through the API. Or any way to detect those changes.

I did search the docs and `php` client library. It looks like its not possible. But i'm asking because I might miss something.

Comment: https://docs.recurly.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: @ceejayoz, thank you it is useful. But essentially what I'm trying to do is getting monthly numbers of subscription upgrades. Webhooks can work for later. But i need data of all times.

Comment: Use webhooks to collect all the data, then analyze it on your end. There also appears to be https://docs.recurly.com/docs/recurly-analytics

Comment: With webhooks it looks like I can't acces the past time data. And that's not the API docs. Its available only on website.